neo4j how to get all the nodes eventually connected to a give node?
I am not trying to get all the connected nodes,
when I run
MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n LIMIT 200
I can see all my nodes and relationships are separated to three groups,

I am trying to find all the nodes connected to a given node (through 1 or multiple relationships), like if I give node3 which is in the center of the bottom right group, can I get back all the nodes in group three?

so I tried
MATCH p=(a:Person {name:'node3'})-[:KNOWS]->(b) return p

but it only returns the node immediately connected to node3, is there anyway we can get all the nodes like shown in group3?


To get all the outgoing KNOWS paths from that specific Person, you can do a variable-length relationship search:
MATCH p=(a:Person {name: 'node3'})-[:KNOWS*]->(b)
RETURN p

However, best practice is to put a reasonable upper bound on the path length to avoid running out of memory or taking forever. For example, to set an upper bound of 7 steps from the starting node:
MATCH p=(a:Person {name: 'node3'})-[:KNOWS*..7]->(b)
RETURN p

